# Typescript error: Initializers are not allowed in ambient context

Tags: angular, typescript

Here im trying to upgrade my Angular2 to Angular4 i'm getting Error as Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error Build:Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts
**Package.js**

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It has nothimg to do with `package.json`, please paste the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: While the code where the error is thrown is a "must" to understand the problem, I wouldn't say that the package.json has nothing to do with the  error. It could well be a versioning problem. But of course, it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Typescript Version. Probably your typescript is outdated. The same issue may also occur when you using old node_modules. Please try using updated node packages

Comment: i'm using node_8.2.1

Comment: Try upgarding your  "typescript": "^2.0.2" to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install -g typescript@latest in terminal to get the latest typescript get installed.